# JavaScript UnitTest: How to test a Jquery Submit() in a click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine, form-submit

I'm fairly new to Javascript UnitTesting with Jasmine. So I don't know how to mock the jQuery Submit(). All my other functions work properly with the same implementation but the .submit() still is executed even with SpyOn.

The code I need to test is :

```
submitQuery: function(query) {
    BoseSiteSearch._setQueryTextField(query);
    if (BoseSiteSearch.isMobile) {
        $('#searchbox').submit();
    } else {
        $('#siteSearchForm').submit();
    }

    return false;
}
```

My Test Code:

```
 describe("submitQuery", function () {
    it('should submit the search query for desktop"',function(){
        loadFixtures('JavaScript-V2/Functions/Bose.SiteSearch.specs.html');
        var query = 'testValue';

        spyOn(BoseSiteSearch,'_setQueryTextField');            
        spyOn($('#siteSearchForm'),'submit'); 

        BoseSiteSearch.submitQuery(query);

        expect(BoseSiteSearch._setQueryTextField).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect($('#siteSearchForm').submit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

**SOLVED**

```
it('should submit the search query for desktop"',function(){
        loadFixtures('JavaScript-V2/Functions/Bose.SiteSearch.specs.html');
        var query = 'testValue';
        // MOCK THE SUBMIT 
        $.fn.submit = function(){}
        spyOn(BoseSiteSearch,'_setQueryTextField');            
        spyOn( $.fn,'submit');

        BoseSiteSearch.submitQuery(query);

        expect(BoseSiteSearch._setQueryTextField).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect( $.fn.submit).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });
```

Comment: You are not writing an integration test nor do you want to unit test `submit` itself, jQuery devs already tested that `submit` works. You therefore should mock out the dependency similar to, i.e: `$.submit = function(){}` then when submit is triggered in your test, your mock is called instead. (not sure if it is `$.submit` or `$.fn.submit` you need to overwrite)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I've implemented like with $.fn.submit
And now it works. Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure if that would work as I was not able to test it in my current environment. Seeing it did though I added it as an answer so future users with similar issues can easier see what worked for you when you mark the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably should add this as an answer for future users with similar issues.

You are not writing an integration test nor do you want to unit test submit itself, jQuery devs already tested that submit works.

Therefore you can mock out the dependency similar to:

```
$.submit = function(){};

// or

$.fn.submit = function(){};
```

Then when `submit` is triggered in your test, your mock is called instead and your test should be able to assert the result.